# redis_om from pypi differs from github

Tags: python, git, redis

I downloaded redis_om using `pip install redis_om=0.0.27` in order to work on my project but I needed to dig into the code further and now I want to fork the github repo so I can continue my work and understand the deltas I made.

I go to github and download the source with the following command:

```
git clone https://github.com/redis-developer/redis-om-python
git checkout v0.0.27
```

I do a folder compare of the content to find that the github version is asynchronous version of the library that is installed in my site-packages making it more cumbersome to see my changes. How do I get the released version of redis_om that is depended on redis and not aredis (the asynchronous version of redis)?

In my site-packages dist information for redis-om installed using the pip command, the metadata shows the same gitrepo that I cloned etc. What am I doing wrong?

```
Metadata-Version: 2.1
Name: redis-om
Version: 0.0.27
Summary: Objecting mapping, and more, for Redis.
Home-page: https://github.com/redis-developer/redis-om-python
```

Comment: I'm sure the question should be asked at https://github.com/redis/redis-om-python/issues

Comment: I think I figured it out. There is a make_sync.py script in the release that changes all the async into sync functions.

Comment: You can answer the question and accept your answer. Please add more details on how to run `make_sync.py`.